# Flask, NGINX, uWSGI random redirection problem after authentication

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

While I run my application on Dev server (Port 5000), user authenticate and it redirect to application home page. But after deploying the application on NGINX, randomly after successfull login, the user return to login page.

[image: While after login user redirect to admin_pagel]

[image: While after login user redirect to login page]